# extend data shortcut in Excel

Tags: excel

I want to extend the date to next line in Excel

I usually use the mouse to hold and drag to next rows to extend the dates

[image]

So in this case, I goto the corner of the cell (circled) and drag it down to extend the dates to next row. Is there a keyboard shortcut for that in Excel?

Like Ctrl+D will copy the value in the upper row and fill the current cell. Is there a keyboard shortcut to make the current row follow the sequence?

Comment: Double-click the little square in the bottom right corner.

Comment: Thanks, I am looking for some keyboard shortcuts, without using the mouse

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/840143/is-there-a-way-to-autofill-cells-in-excel-2013-with-keyboard-shortcuts/840169#840169